# Ajax tab control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

There is a issue when we use ajax tab control on a web page and when that page is accessed in fire fox 7.0 version then ajax tabs does not show. can anyone solve this?

Yes i got error in fire fox error console. The error is

Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount"  code: "1" nsresult: "0x80530001 (NS_ERROR_DOM_INDEX_SIZE_ERR)"  location: "http://localhost:1573/myPage.aspx?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ScriptManager1_HiddenField&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bAjaxControlToolkit%2c+Version%3d3.0.30930.28736%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d28f01b0e84b6d53e%3aen-US%3ab0eefc76-0092-471b-ab62-f3ddc8240d71%3ae2e86ef9%3a1df13a87%3aee0a475d%3ac4c00916%3a6e0e9b78%3a9ea3f0e2%3ac7c04611%3acd120801%3a3858419b%3a96741c43%3a38ec41c0%3afde3863c%3a9e8e87e9%3a4c9865be%3aba594826%3a757f92c2%3abae32fb7%3a182913ba Line: 16"]

Comment: Are you getting any JavaScript errors in the error console in Firefox?

Comment: I had used ajax tab control in my project and it's working fine in firefox 7.0.1 version.. Can you check which kind of error, you get!!! Please, check it in firefox error console.

Comment: I don't think @sikender used enough exclamation points there :p

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the exact same error but on the AsyncFileUpload control. After doing some research, I narrowed the problem down to the actual AjaxControlToolkit itself.

I was running an older version, so I upgraded to the latest version as of November 16th, 2011 and the problem was resolved.

So try [the latest version](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/) either by direct download or via the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.

Also, it looks like there is a duplicate question here: [Problems with Ajax Tabs control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721881/problems-with-ajax-tabs-control)